# What is the completeness property in General?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm new to Real Analysis, and I have this property in my text book that goes by the name "Order Completeness Property" of $\mathbb{R}$. I understand that it basically means every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above or below has a supremum or infimum respectively.

But I'm wondering what exactly is the order completeness property in general? What does it mean to be "order complete"? First of all what order are we talking about here. I'm familiar with the partial order, total order, well order only.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the order is complete, not that something is order complete.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I'm not sure what you mean but Mind = Blown..

Comment: I think he means that "complete" is meant as a property of the order itself, and not of the subset of R to be "order complete" (no comment on whether that's actually what the book says, that's just how I interpret the other comment).